# How to use Many-to-many relationships

Tags: django, django-models

I am using **Many-to-many relationships** in my app and I am not able to feed data into the table which is by default created by the Django to ensure the Many-to-many relationships.It gives the error in method  (**def Set_Checkout_Attributes(request):**) that **'Customer_check_attributes' object has no attribute 'set_customers'** If I replace set_customers with **set_users** the error will remain same.

The models which I used are:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user        =models.OneToOneField(User)
    birthday    =models.DateField()

class Customer_check_attributes(models.Model):
    users       =models.ManyToManyField(User)
    billing_add =models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True , null=
```

My view.py is as

```
def CustomerRegistration(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Registration_Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user=User.objects.create_user(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], email=form.cleaned_data['email'], password = form.cleaned_data['password'])
            user.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            user.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            user.save()



            customer=Customer(user=user, website=form.cleaned_data['website'], birthday=form.cleaned_data['birthday'], store=form.cleaned_data['store'], welcomemail=form.cleaned_data['welcomemail'])  
            customer.save()

                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
        else:
            check_form=Check_Attribute_Form()
            context={'form':form, 'check':check_form}
                return render_to_response('customer/customer_register.html',context , context_instance=RequestContext(request)) 
    else:
        ''' user is not submitting the form, show them a blank registration form '''

            form = Registration_Form()
        check_form = Check_Attribute_Form()
            context={'form':form,'check':check_form}
            return render_to_response('customer/customer_register.html',context , context_instance=RequestContext(request))


####################################### checkout attributes ##################################################


def Checkout_Attributes(request):



    check_form = Check_Attribute_Form()
    context={'form':check_form}
    return render_to_response('customer/checkout.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def Set_Checkout_Attributes(request):

    #if request.user.is_authenticated():
        #return HttpResponseRedirect('/checkout/')

    if request.method == 'POST':
            check_form = Check_Attribute_Form(request.POST)
            #if check_form.is_valid():
            customer_check=Customer_check_attributes(billing_add=check_form.data['billing_add'],shipping_add=check_form.data['shipping_add'],payment_method=check_form.data['payment_method'],shipping_method=check_form.data['shipping_method'],reward_points=check_form.data['reward_points'])
            customer_check.save()
            customer_check.set_customers([user.id])
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
        #else:
            #check_form=Check_Attribute_Form()
            #return render_to_response('a.html',{'check_form':check_form} , context_instance=RequestContext(request)) 
    else:
            return render_to_response('f')
```

I am got struck here for two days but I can't solve it Please help me.

*Thanks*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
customer_check.users.add(your user instance)
```

I think you are trying to use

```
user.customer_check_set.
```

but you just use wrongly.

if  class  x has M2M field y you can reach y directly from x instance like this

> x.y

and you can reach x from y like this:

> y.x_set

Have fun with django

Comment: I used that one but it shows the error of **now it shows this int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'SimpleLazyObject'**

Comment: customer_check.set_customers([user.id]) change it customer_check.users.add(user) ->>> not user id. think object oriented man:) we work on objects not their ids.

Comment: I told you already that but it reply me that global name user is not define

Comment: and if i define it as **thikonom** told me thaen it gives an error *int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'SimpleLazyObject' *